# Search index in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, search

I have an array of arrays:

Dim IDMUsers As List(Of Array)

I populate this Array with information. Example:
[{Data1a,Data2a,Data3a,....,Data30a},{Data1b,Data2b,Data3b,....,Data30b},{Data1c,Data2c,Data3c,....,Data30c}]

Now, i need to find for example "Data3b" and the function must return the register number where it is, in this case it must return record number 2. ie {Data1b,Data2b,Data3b,....,Data30b}

I'm working in VB.Net.

My code is:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim TecoReader As New FileManagement
    Dim IDMUsers As List(Of Array)

   ' Populate Array
    IDMUsers = TecoReader.ReadFromFile(My.Settings.ActivosIDMFilePath, My.Settings.CharSeparator)

   Console.writeline (SearchInArray("text"))
end sub


Private Function SearchInArray(ByVal ToSearchFor As String) As String
    For Each Register In IDMUsers
        For Each Field In Register
            If Field = ToSearchFor Then
                Return Register(26) & " - " & Register(27)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return ""
End Function
```

It works with the SeachInArray function, but i have a large array (20K registers), so is very slowly and i need a better approach.

Comment: Does the data always have a specific format(f.e. first index ends with 'a', second ends with 'b', ...)? I mean, what rules exist? If it cannot contain arbitrary data, you could use an other collection like Dictionary instead.

Comment: The data doesn't have that format. It was only to represent the Array Information. I cannot change the type of IDMUsers. It have to be list(of array) type of.

Comment: If you cannot change the collection-type and the data has no specific format, that's the only option(LINQ approaches wouldn't be more effficient). You could use a database instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

My code is in C#, may be it is helpful for you to avoid at least one **FOR EACH** loop....

```
int mainArrayIndex = 0;
        string arrayIndex = string.Empty;
        int searchIdex = 0;
        foreach (string[] item in jaggedArray)
        {
            mainArrayIndex++;
            searchIdex = Array.BinarySearch(item, "H");
            if (searchIdex > 0)
            {
                arrayIndex = mainArrayIndex + "," + searchIdex.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anand. I've resolved the problem in a different way. Thanks again

Comment: @Oblongo is answer is helpful for u ?